# Onchange of a dropdown,bind checkboxlist without page postback(javascript/webservice)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkboxlist and dropdown on my page,checkboxlist is populated depending upon the selected value in dropdown. Its working fine as far as I am using the server side event OnSelectedIndexChange of the dropdown-

```
protected void ddlCtype_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sdsMultipleCategory.DataBind(); //sqldatabase of chklist 
    CheckBoxList chklist = (CheckBoxList)fvCompany.FindControl("chklist");
    chklist.DataBind();
}
```

Problem with this is as its server side event it postback my page,Is there any way to do the same functionality without page postback,like cascading dropdown in ajax.Is it possible to use webservice,pagemethod or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
> Problem with this is as its server side event it postback my page
```

Is it a real problem? If so use UpdatePanel to update chklist only.

Comment: Thanx inser,Its the requirement that the page should not post back until 'submit' button is clicked. Update panel,yes it has solved my problem but as update panel has a limitation that when it is used with formview control which has both the <InsertItemTemplate> and <EditItemTemplate>,It shows an error message to the controls those are in update panel,If we give different names to the controls within update panel then it work,,I would like to know is it possible to use webservice or pagemethod or any other way??

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try something like this:
http://devarchive.net/loading_user_controls_using_with_page_methods.aspx